# What is the c# of this vb code?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I need to convert this vb code to c#, my problem is that I don't understand what is item in vb and what is its equivalent in c#.

```
Dim summary As New DataTable();
Dim row As DataRow = summary.NewRow()
Dim info As Hashtable = reader.Info
        For Each key As String In info.Keys
            Select Case key
                Case "Title"
                    row("Title") = info.Item(key)
                Case "Author"
                    row("Author") = info.Item(key)
                Case "Subject"
                    row("Subject") = info.Item(key)
            End Select
        Next
        summary.Rows.Add(row)
```

Comment: See [Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/)

Comment: If you remove the semicolon from the first line, LarsTech's Code Converter link will work.

Answer (score 3):

C# equivalent would be `info[key]`.  You can find additional information on Microsoft website: [Hashtable.Item Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.item.aspx)